# Why is the blessing of Mezonos not mentioned in the Mishnah?

Tags: blessing, mishna, tractate-brachot, mezonot-beracha

The Mishnayos of the sixth perek of Berachos discuss all the different blessings which one makes on food, with the exception of the blessing 'borei minei mezonos'. Why is this not mentioned?

Comment: Could it be categorized like the other _b'rachos_ in that _mishna_? It seems it would be more complicated.

Comment: Tosefta berachot 4:6 and 7 does mention it. Just commenting to help guide answers...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79385/9682

Answer (score 5):

The first **פני יהושע** in Keitzad Mevarchim discusses this question.  His suggestion is that the Mishna is only listing berachos that include a lot of different species, to contrast with R' Yehuda who is brought at the end of the Mishna and says each species needs its own specific blessing.

According to **Tosefos** in the discussion of kimcha d'chiti on berachos 36a, it seems that Mezonos would not be a "פרי" - Tosefos understands that only bread is considered to be a פרי of wheat (See Tos. [38a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=73&size=1) s.v. האי דובשא that מיני מזונות has עלוי אחרינא בפת and therefore would not be a פרי since it has been processed), as opposed to mezonos which has lost its פרי status through being processed.  The Mishna is discussing blessings on פירות, as it begins with כיצד מברכין על הפירות, and therefore Mezonos would not belong there.

Comment: any forthcoming explanation for the downvote?  Out of curiosity.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146. (I upvoted, myself.)

Comment: @msh210 I downvoted that post :) and to make it more ironic, I got a pop-up asking me to leave a comment about my downvote to be constructive!!!  But I was asking out of curiosity, as I pointed out - I don't know what was unhelpful about this post.